Applescript error -1728 while moving file to different folder
I am trying to move the currently viewed file, in my case images, in the preview to a different folder with AppleScript. Idea is to create a shortcut with this AppleScript to easily go through my images and sort them.
I am getting the error 1728 "file can not be read".
tell application "Preview" to set thefile to path of front document


tell application "Finder"
    set p to "Users:XXX:XXX:XXX:Favoriten"
    set favorit to POSIX path of p
    move POSIX file thefile to favorit with replacing
end tell


Finder doesn't use POSIX paths, so you need to not use them, or coerce to POSIX file.

Here is something to try. In general, there are advantages to using System Events to move files, notably speed.
A useful quirk here is that System Events seems to automatically handle the path of the file.
tell application "Preview" to set pef to path of front document
--> "/Users/user/Downloads/usage/abc123.jpg"

set dst to (path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:desto:"

tell application "System Events"
    
    move file pef to folder dst
    --> file "MacHD:Users:user:Desktop:desto:abc123.jpg" of application "System Events" 
    
end tell

With some minor tweaks, you can work with multiple documents as System Events can work with lists for some commands.
-- generate list of paths for open documents
tell application "Preview" to set pef to path of documents

set dst to (path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:desto:"

tell application "System Events"
    -- move list to destination folder
    move pef to folder dst  
end tell

